# How to set Apple Watch title for VoiceOver AccessibilityLabel

Tags: accessibility, title, apple-watch, watchos, wkinterfacecontroller

Is there any way to change the AccessibilityLabel of a WKInterfaceController title?

Or to turn off just the title VoiceOver?

I have shortened the title to X|Y to show the user what they are viewing but this is not very user friendly for someone using VoiceOver as it reads as "X bar Y" when it should either be turned off or read "Item X of Y"

I am doing a hack right now to check for VoiceOver and set the title but this obviously will not display well on a limited size Apple Watch screen:

```
    let voiceOverON: Bool = WKAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning()
    if voiceOverON
    {
        self.setTitle("Exercise \(itemSelected + 1) of \(itemsTotal).")
    }
    else
    {
        self.setTitle("\(itemSelected + 1)|\(itemsTotal)")
    }
```

Any ideas that might help the visually impaired?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RADAR filed: 28355257 - WKInterfaceController does not support Accessibility